# Single chapter in two languages

Tags: sectioning, chapters, languages

I'm writing a thesis in english but I have to insert some abstracts in Italian (my native language). In particular I have to write an introduction of each chapter in Italian. I mean

> Chapter 1 (in Italian)
>
> Chapter 1 (in English)

Is there a way to do that?
I've been trying many workaround and googling but nothing is helping me.

If I try with the `otherlanguage` tag latex creates two separate chapters, and if I use `*` I don't have the word 'Chapter' (in Italian) in my thesis.

Comment: Can you be clearer about your aim? The chapter header is to be repeated twice in the same page or do you want separate pages?

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood your question correctly, what you want to do is use the `\chapter{name here}` command twice, but get the same chapter number for each?

In that case, you can insert the command `\addtocounter{chapter}{-1}` right before the second `\chapter{ }` to reduce the value of LaTeX's internal chapter counter and it should give you the same number for both chapters.

Comment: Yes, that's my idea. But the next issue is the contents section, I don't wanna see two chapters 1 there and if I add `*` latex deletes the 'Chapter 1' part from the chapter.

Comment: Maybe this could be a solution. (I'm having the same problem) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110840/how-to-remove-chapter-numbering-without-removing-it-from-tableofcontents