# How to remove chapter numbering without removing it from table of contents

Tags: numbering, chapters

It seems I have spent two days trying to find out the solution to my problem. I have just finished typing my M.Sc thesis using Latex (MIKTEX 2.9). Unfortunately, all my chapters begin with the chapter number at the top left corner of a page. My supervisor asked me to remove that numbering of the chapters without removing them from the table of contents.

I have tried my best to do that but I failed. The last attempt I made is `\chapter*{chapter title}`, the moment I compiled my work, I found out that it began sectioning from 0.1, 0.2, and so on, which I don't like.

---

I have this code inside my thesis:

```
\chapter*
{\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad\quad \large{CHAPTER ONE}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CHAPTER ONE}

%Introduction}{}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\onehalfspacing
\begin{center}
\textbf{\large \quad INTRODUCTION}
\end{center}

\section{Introduction} This chapter gives a brief highlight on the concept of the Newton and quasi-Newton methods for solving nonlinear system of equations. The chapter contains motivation of the study, the aim and objectives, scope and limitations, methodology of the research. It includes some basic fundamentals and definitions of some basic terms.
```

---

After compiling, it gives me this:

```
CHAPTER ONE

INTRODUCTION

0.1 Introduction
This chapter gives a brief highlight on the concept of the Newton and quasi-
Newton methods for solving nonlinear system of equations. The chapter contains
motivation of the study, the aim and objectives, scope and limitations, methodol-
ogy of the research. It includes some basic fundamentals and definitions of some
basic terms.
```

NB: Please observe how the section "Introduction" is numbered. I want it to be numbered 1.1 not 0.1.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

By adding `\setcounter{chapter}{n}` before the nth chapter seems to fix the numbering of subsections issue. Also though, you have to reset the numbering of sections. An easy way to do this would to just define a new command. For example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\newcommand{\mychapter}[2]{
    \setcounter{chapter}{#1}
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \chapter*{#2}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2}
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\mychapter{0}{Acknowledgments}
\mychapter{1}{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Further Introduction}
\mychapter{2}{Experiments}
\section{Experiment One}
\section{Experiment Two}
\end{document}
```

[image: Chapters have no numbers, sections follow numbering that would be there if chapters had]

Comment: Is there a way to use this, but still be able to refer to these chapters with `\ref`? I'd like to have my cake, but eat it too.

Comment: Never mind, fixed this by including `\refstepcounter{chapter}`.

Answer (score 38):

You can do something as is done in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55465/remove-dots-page-numbers-from-toc).
Use code similar to the following:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Acknowledgments}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments}
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\chapter{Experiments}
\chapter{Conclusion}
\end{document}
```

The idea is to use `\chapter*{}` for unnumbered chapters and then add them to the toc explicitly with the `\addcontentsline`.
Which gives this result:

[image]

Comment: This still suffers from "it begin sectioning from 0.1,0.2, and so on, which I don't like". Doesn't it? I think the idea might be to redefine the chapter* so as to trigger the chapter counter without typesetting the chapter number explicitly. I'll post an answer if I figure out how to do it.

Comment: Thats because it doesn't really make typographical sense to have numbered sections in an unnumbered chapter. Would in the example above the chapter `Experiments` have number 3? It would look really strange imo.

Comment: If I understand the OP, he does not want to number any chapter at all. Not saying it makes typographical sense, but, we could try answer his question instead of tell him what he already knows.

Comment: Of course kan you truly understood what I meant. @Mythio, I have already tried your answer but still I have the section numbered 0.1, 0.2 and so on. What do you suggest? I like the section numbering in this form: 1.1, 1.2 ... for chapter one and 2.1, 2.2, ... for chapter two, and so on.

Comment: @Jite  I have class now. I'll come back and see what I can do.

Comment: Ok, have a nice class.

Comment: @Jite; so if im understanding correctly you don't want chapter numbers at all, but you want chapters in the toc similar to the `acknowledgements` in my example. However, you do want sections to be numbered according to the number the chapter would have IF it was shown?

Comment: @Mythio yes that is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 20):

If I read that correctly, you want chapters to have numbers. These numbers should be shown in the ToC. But the numbers should not be printed in the chapter heading. This can be achieved with the `titlesec` package:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\Large\bfseries} % format
  {}                % label
  {0pt}             % sep
  {\huge}           % before-code

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Acknowledgments}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Further Introduction}
\chapter{Experiments}
\section{Experiment One}
\section{Experiment Two}
\end{document}
```

The ToC then looks like

[image: ToC]

while the chapter heads in the text look like

[image: text]

Comment: How do you remove the numbers from the ToC as well?

Answer (score 8):

I don't think that you want to remove the numbering: You want to use words (one, two) instead of numbers in the heading. This can be done (for english) e.g. with the numname package. The exact code depends on your class, here is an example for book:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{numname}
\makeatletter
%Redefine chapterheading:
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \numtoName{\c@chapter}
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{abc}
\section{abc}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

None of the other solutions worked for me. Here's what worked:

```
\tableofcontents

\phantomsection
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}

This is the beginning
```

Note the use of `\phantomsection`. Thanks to this old thread on [LaTeX.org from '08](http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1750).