# Remove chapter num. without removing it from ToC with minitoc

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

Here, I removed chapter numbering  for some chapters and sections without removing them from ToC using

```
\chapter*{Acknowledgments}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments}
```

and I've tried to add a mini table of contents using `\usepackage{minitoc}` and `\minitoc`.

Here my code Latex :

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue
           ,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Acknowledgments}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments}
\minitoc


\section*{Acknowledgments 1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acknowledgments 1}




\chapter{Introduction}
\minitoc
\section{sec1}
\section{sec2}
\end{document}
```

But :
- no mini ToC was created for the first chapter (with removed numbering)
- and the mini Toc in the 2nd chapter was these for the 1st one.
[image]
thank you for help

Comment: I've used these two solutions in my code https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110840/how-to-remove-chapter-numbering-without-removing-it-from-tableofcontents and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3001/list-sections-of-chapter-at-beginning-of-that-chapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicit `\addcontentsline` commands on `\minitoc` - chapter level confuse `minitoc`.

Use `\addstarredchapter{Acknowledgments}` instead, it is a `minitoc` command.

The `\addcontentsline` for the `section*` entry is alright, however, since it goes to the correct ToC.

Please note that `\addstarredchapter` is only for the `ToC` entry, the `\chapter*` macro is still needed.

For other purposes with `\doparttoc` and `\dosecttoc` there are `\addstarredpart` and `\addstarredsection` macros respectively.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue
           ,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\chapter*{Acknowledgments}
\addstarredchapter{Acknowledgments}
\minitoc


\section*{Acknowledgments 1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acknowledgments 1}




\chapter{Introduction}
\minitoc
\section{sec1}
\section{sec2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Math: You're welcome. Happy TeXing.